`verbatim*` environment in a `minipage` defined by a `\newcommand` does not work
Still a novice at LaTeX - I was attempting to define a custom command for creating minipages of a certain width using this code:
\newcommand{\col}[2]{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}}

This works for stuff like
\col{0.3}{\includegraphics*[scale=0.3]{dfsbfs.png}}

but for some reason beginning a verbatim* environment or lstlisting environment gives a variety of errors when trying to compile using pdflatex; something like this doesn't work:
\col{0.35}{
    Order in which DFS visits nodes:
    $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$
    \begin{verbatim*}
    blah blah code
    \end{verbatim*}
}

How should I go about implementing \col such that it works for the example above?

In general, verbatim commands cannot be arguments to macros.

You should define col to be an environment not a command. verbatim would work and the environment syntax is generally more suitable for anything that takes larger segments of text.

\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{col}[1]{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}

\begin{col}{0.35}
Order in which DFS visits nodes:
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$
\begin{verbatim*}
blah blah code
\end{verbatim*}
\end{col}
\end{document}


I was under the mistaken impression that newcommand and newenvironment did the same thing but allowed for two different syntaxes to call the macro. What does newenvironment do differently internally that allows verbatim to work?

@invisi. a macro parses its argument first, by which time all the special characters are special and it's too late to stop that.  an environment doesn't (usually) scan its body in advance.

While you cannot, in general, include verbatim environments as part of an argument to a macro, you can create and save the verbatim content in a box, in advance, and then regurgitate the box as part of the macro argument, using the verbatimbox package.
Here, the \strut optional argument to the verb-box ensures the box has proper vertical spacing for typesetting with other material.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\col}[2]{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\strut]
blah blah 
code
\end{verbbox}
\col{0.35}{
    Order in which DFS visits nodes:
    $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$\\
    \theverbbox\\
    Continued commentary.
}
\end{document}


If you want verb-box to appear inline (in fact, it is always typeset inline), you could do it this way:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\col}[2]{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}blah blah code\end{verbbox}
\col{0.35}{
    Order in which DFS visits nodes:
    $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$
    \theverbbox{}
    Continued commentary.
}
\end{document}


